# SQL: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '%' to data type int

Tags: sql, type-conversion, ssms, varchar

I have looked at the various responses for this type conversion error and think I am dealing with something different entirely.

I am getting the above error when attempting to select any columns from a table in SSMS.  However, a different user can go in and execute the code just fine.  Even a simple 'SelectTopNRows' command produces the error. I have removed columns below as an example.

```
`SELECT TOP 1000
[Account ID]
,[Account Name]
,[Billing City]
,[Billing Country]
,[Billing Latitude]
,[Billing Longitude]
,[Billing State/Province]
,[Billing Street]
,[Billing Zip/Postal Code]
FROM [SFDC].[dbo].[Accounts]`
```

Basic stuff, obviously, yet I get nothing.

To reiterate, the code works for another SSMS user.  Also, queries on other tables in the same database/connection work fine, however it is two specific tables that are generating this same error upon execution.

Please help!

Comment: Regional settings in windows? Please check them for you and the other user.

Comment: This might be it, I am not an admin on the server, but I am trying to get a hold of someone that can dig into the regional settings for me.  Thanks for the suggestion @abhi